# Spring Boot Data JPA: One-to-One Relationship with Shared Primary Key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Spring Boot Data JPA. I am testing the one-to-one relationship with shared primary key between `Customer` and `Phone` entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Phone phone;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String number;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Customer customer;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

Here is the `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/springtest?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When I run the simple test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringTestApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        customerRepository.deleteAll();
        phoneRepository.deleteAll();
        
        final Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("John");
        customer.setLastName("Doe");
        
        customerRepository.save(customer);
        
        final Phone phone = new Phone();
        phone.setNumber("1234567890");
        phone.setCustomer(customer);
        
        phoneRepository.save(phone);
    }
}
```

the last line of code (`phoneRepository.save(phone)`) throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
detached entity passed to persist: org.code.entities.Customer
```

I have extensively googled the exception, but still cannot fix the issue. I appreciate any help.

Some additional information that might be helpful:

- Spring Boot 2.4.0
- Java 11
- Generated the project using https://start.spring.io/

Comment: What happens if you apply `@Transactional` to your test method?

Comment: (Note in general that you should avoid adding excess annotations like `@JoinColumn` unless your database schema actually requires them.)

Comment: When I apply `@Transactional`, I don't get the exception anymore, but I don't see the a phone record in the database. I do see a customer record though.

Comment: The reason I added `@JoinColumn` is because of this post: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. Here is the detail. The relationship between the `Customer` and the `Phone` entities is bidirectional and one-to-one. Notice that `Phone` is the owning side of the relationship because its primary key is not auto-generated and its primary key is also the foreign key to the `Customer` entity. After instantiating these entities, we have to cross-reference each object in the other one through the lines:

```
phone.setCustomer(customer);
customer.setPhone(phone);
```

Then, we have to first save the phone object followed by the customer object.

Here is the new test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringTestApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        phoneRepository.deleteAll();
        customerRepository.deleteAll();
        
        final Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName("John");
        customer.setLastName("Doe");
        
        final Phone phone = new Phone();
        phone.setNumber("1234567890");
        phone.setCustomer(customer);
        customer.setPhone(phone);
        
        phoneRepository.save(phone);
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```